# What is a state of motion?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, definition

The introduction to Einstein’s 1905 EDoMB contains:  Light is always propagated in empty space with definite speed $c$, which is independent of the state of motion of the emitting body.

What is state of motion?

1. An emitting body, a distant star or galaxy, moves with respect to ourselves, earthbound observers.  Motion is relative motion of source and observer.  Although the source approaches or recedes, its signal always impinges on the observer at speed $c$, not $c + v$ or $c – v$.
2. An emitting body is anchored at the origin of axis X′ which axis moves relatively to another axis X with speed $v$.  The emitting body fixed at x′ = 0 sends a signal to x′ ( oneway distance ) and back, the signal then covering distance of 2x′, and it does so in time t′.  The quotient is 2x′/t′ = c.  The quotient is independent of the state of motion of axis X′.

Item #1 involves relative motion of source and observer while #2 does not.  Source and observer are co-located at $x′ = 0$.

Is state of motion #1 or #2?

It’s likely that EDoMB puts forward #2.

Comment: On the one hand, you ask what is "state of motion".  But you actually seem to be asking if Einstein is referring to the one-way speed of light or the two-way speed of light.  For what it's worth, the two-way speed of light is a measurement independent of (distant) clock synchronization while a one-way measurement is not.

Comment: I don't think you have it quite right but yes oneway versus twoway is a big deal.  Einstein made a big deal of it.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Since motion in special relativity (for bodies of invariant mass $m$) is relative, „state of motion of the emitting body” simply means that it is of no relevance whatsoever if the emitting body/source is (observed to be) at rest in the IRF $A$ or under uniform motion with velocity $\mathbf{v}$ in the IRF $B$. Nothing more.

You can also perceive the expression "state of motion" as "kinematical state", i.e. an esemble of {body of mass m, observer, axes of coordinates assigned to the observer, watch, coordinate of body of mass m wrt to the observer and velocity of the body of mass m wrt to the observer}.

Answer (score 0):

I probably misstated the whole thing.  An emitting body moves with respect to empty space or with respect to an ether which is not detectable.  That is ‘state of motion’.  Emissions are along an axis of the body and along this axis a ray of light has speed c regardless of state of motion.  The body is in motion in principle or in the abstract.  Nobody observes this motion.  If there is an observer, he is associated with body, on an axis of the body on which there is a ray of light.  He always observes speed c.  In essence, this is the Michelson-Morley device

EdoMB updates that conception with Principle 2 in Section 2:   Any ray of light moves in the “stationary” system of co-ordinates with determined velocity c, whether the ray be emitted by a stationary or by a moving body.

The emitting body now moves with respect to this ‘stationary’ system and further the body is observed in such motion by a ‘stationary’ observer.  Because there is no such thing as absolute rest, ‘stationary’ is semantic and as a practical matter it means that a synchrony clock set-up is in the stationary system.  The system is described in Section 1.  A ray in the system, according to the clock set-up, has speed c.   The ray originates at clock A, goes to clock B and then back to clock A and has speed c by definition.  Principle 2 enters by allowing the signal which originates at clock A to be ‘emitted by a moving body’ – a body which the system observes to be in motion.

It is a highly artificial set-up.  Nevertheless the source and the observer are in relative motion, but the observer will not detect relative motion in the form of c + v or c – v.